# What is the best way to utilize memory inside of "session(_:didUpdate:)" method?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, apple-vision

My use case is I want to calculate various gestures of a hand (the first hand) seen by the camera. I am able to find body anchors and hand anchors and poses. [See my video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDAe6ELqO8M).
I am trying to utilize previous position SIMD3 information to calculate what kind of gesture was demonstrated. I did see the example posted by Apple which shows pinching to write virtually, I am not sure that a buffer is the right solution for something like this.

A specific example of what I am trying to do is detect a swipe, long-press, tap as if the user is wearing a pair of AR glasses (made by Apple one day). For clarification I want to raycast from my hand and perform a gesture on an Entity or Anchor.

Here is a snippet for those of you that want to know how to get body anchors:

```
public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    let capturedImage = frame.capturedImage

    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: capturedImage,
                                                    orientation: .right,
                                                    options: [:])
    let handPoseRequest = VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequest()
    //let bodyPoseRequest = VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest()

    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([handPoseRequest])
        guard let observation = handPoseRequest.results?.first else {
            return
        }
        // Get points for thumb and index finger.
        let thumbPoints = try observation.recognizedPoints(.thumb)
        let indexFingerPoints = try observation.recognizedPoints(.indexFinger)
        let pinkyFingerPoints = try observation.recognizedPoints(.littleFinger)
        let ringFingerPoints = try observation.recognizedPoints(.ringFinger)
        let middleFingerPoints = try observation.recognizedPoints(.middleFinger)
        self.detectHandPose(handObservations: observation)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform image request.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kimate, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I would like to grab an entity and perform gestures, I have a working version of this but I am sure I am doing it incorrectly. I will post most my solution when I clean it up. I want to do gestures similar to this video: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd2GK0qDtRg>

Comment: any solution @KimateRichards?